# Unable to open video from C++ in opencv. It works from python

Tags: python, c++, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use open cv (2.4.9) video support from within C++. However, when I try to open a video file with `cv::VideoCapture` I get

```
warning: Error opening file (/tmp/opencv-mLsrDm/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:545)
WARNING: Couldn't read movie file 11:28:39.mp4
```

Using `cv2.VideoCapture` from within python on the same file works. The python wrappers are from the same build of opencv so I'm a bit perplexed.

Mac os 10.9.4. OpenCV is built with ffmpeg (but no quicktime) via homebrew.

I'm linking against all the libraries that the the python cv2.so is linked against.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that ffmpeg doesn't like file names like `11:28:39.mp4`. Renaming the file to `test.mp4` makes things work.

Comment: It is not working for me? could some body help me to debug the issue. I am trying to capture video from file but it is giving the following error.Command:  cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.mp4')
Error:  "WARNING: Couldn't read movie file test.mp4"